# Why event listener persists after manual removal

Tags: javascript

All,

I try to build a resizer UI like this:

[image]

My code is like:

```
           <span class="grabber" draggable="false" @mousedown="grab"></span>

            grab: function(e) {
                var initX = e.screenX;

                var mousemove = function(e) {
                    var offset = e.screenX - initX
                    initX = e.screenX;
                }
                var cancel = function(e) {
                    $(document).off("mousemove")
                    $(document).off("mouseup")
                }
                $(document).on("mousemove", mousemove)
                $(document).on("mouseup", cancel)
                mousemove = null;
                cancel = null;
            }
```

Basic idea is: I attach that `grab` event handler to mousedown, inside which I listen to mousemove until mouseup, then I remove those two event handlers from document.

I am pretty new to Chrome Performance tool, so I just simply record some drag of that resizer, then mouseup and drag again.

**The result is confused, especially the number of listener goes up like crazy(but there seems no memory leak). I wonder where did I do wrong?**

[image]

Comment: *Please* include your code as text. Even better, make it a runnable snippet

Comment: We need more information about how you are using `grab` from what you have said probably calling grab in a loop over and over and attaching the listeners every time.

Comment: @powerc9000 Thanks, I update the code part. I just use Vue.js

Comment: Instead of adding and removing the handler, it might be better to set and clear a flag variable that says whether to do what you want, and check that variable in the handler.

Comment: @Barmar Could you show a lil demo?

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening here:

`<span class="grabber" draggable="false" @mousedown="grab"></span>`

every time mousedown happens vue runs `grab`

The safer thing to do in this case is attach the events directly to `e.target` also setting your handler function to null in the `cancel` function.

```
 grab: function(e) {
                var initX = e.screenX;
                var target = e.target;

                var mousemove = function(e) {
                    var offset = e.screenX - initX
                    initX = e.screenX;
                }
                var cancel = function(e) {
                    $(target).off("mousemove")
                    $(target).off("mouseup")
                    mousemove = null;
                    cancel = null;
                }
                $(target).on("mousemove", mousemove)
                $(target).on("mouseup", cancel)

            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I used to use e.target, but sometimes when you drag it fast,  mousemove can not happen on it.  I set mousemove and cancel to null at the end of grab.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable instead of adding and removing the handler.

```
var mouseIsDown = false;
$(document).on("mousedown", function() {
    mouseIsDown = true;
});
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    mouseIsDown = false;
})
$(document).on("mousemove", function() {
    if (mouseIsDown) {
        // do what you want
    }
});
```

The `mousedown` handler could be attached to specific elements that you can grab, rather than `document`.

Comment: Thanks, but some of DOM elements could manually prevent the event bubble up, which may mess up that mouseDown

Comment: @Kuan That's why you would probably attach it to the specific grab points, which I assume is what you have in your real code.

Comment: So u are saying u agree with my way or u still suggest ur way?

Comment: I'm saying do it my way, but attach the mousedown handler to the elements that you can grab. Just like I said in the last line of the answer.